# Flask SQLite SQalchemy Deleting Entry via ID Number

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm trying out SQLite together with flask, I have done adding entries and showing it all. Now I'm stuck at my delete function. So I figured out I would try asking for help. here's my algorithm:

```
@app.route('/deleted', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def deleted():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.form['id']:
            flash('Please enter the right number!','error')
        else:
            student1 = Students(request.form['id'])
            x = Students.query.filter_by(id=student1)
            db.session.delete(x)
            db.session.commit()

            flash('Record was deleted successfully ')
            return redirect(url_for('show_all'))
    return render_template('deleted.html')
```

and here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>

      <h3>S Kickout the student</h3>
      <hr/>

      {%- for category, message in get_flashed_messages(with_categories = true) %}
         <div class = "alert alert-danger">
            {{ message }}
         </div>
      {%- endfor %}

      <form action = "/deleted/{{id}}" method = "post">
         <label for = "id">Id Number</label><br>
         <input type = "text" name = "id" placeholder = "Student Id" /><br>
         <input type = "submit" value = "Delete" />

      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

can anybody tell me where I did wrong? I can't figure it out. It's easy but I don't just get why I'm getting a NOT FOUND. Error on my localhost. Any help would be appreciated. I'm getting nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by removing the `id` from the action in the template :

```
<form action = "/deleted" method = "post">
```

Since the method is POST, and the form stores the `id`, you can access it with `request.form['id']`.